# Restore formatted Partition Table on LVM Physical

Tags: linux, partition, lvm, data-recovery

I have a machine (guest VM running CentOS 6.5) with 2 disks. Main OS on `sda` and then a 2TB LVM on the second `sdc`.

I added 2 more 2TB disks to the machine and was going through the process of formatting then using `fdisk` to add to the LVM, but I fdisk'd the wrong disk, `sdc`. Two new disks came up as `sdb` and `sdd`. Like an idiot I didn't check `fdisk -l` properly before continuing.

I created a new primary partition on 1, and then over-wrote the system id again to 8e (LVM).

So `sdc` now has a new UUID and a new partition table.

Anyone know how I can recover this using the vgcfgrestore util? Can I just overwrite the new UUID over the old one in the vg1(volume-group-backup-file) and run the restore?

Answer (score 2):

I did this same thing myself the other night while debugging gparted.  I used `dd if=/dev/zero count=1 of=/dev/sdc` to wipe out the dos partition table, then `pvcreate --uuid xxxx --norestorefile` to reinitialize the lvm header, and finally `vcfgrestore` to restore from the backup in /etc/lvm/backup, which you can also look at to find what the uuid of the drive was before to give to pvcreate.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Psusi

This would have been far easier than what I did in the end. I used testdisk with a deep analysis to re-rediscover the underlying partition. This took a few hours as it was a 89% full 2TB drive.

Once I had found the drive and its dimension (automatically by testdisk), I wrote the changes.

One caveat though is to select intel as the partition type. if you select none, it cannot write the results that you find.

Thanks for the answer!