# recover lvm after loosing partition table

Tags: linux, partition, lvm, data-recovery

On one of my hard drives had a few physical volumes/partitions and lvm on them. And then I lost partition table. I still have files from /etc/lvm/*
how can I recover my data?

Comment: Check out http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121808/restore-formated-partition-table-on-lvm-physical